Laplace equation in-between two non-concentric spheres
We fix two spheres $S_1$ and $S_2$ (without interior) and suppose that $S_2$ is entirely inside $S_1$. For example, $S_1 = \{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 25\}$ and $S_2 = \{(x-1)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\}$.
How to solve the following BVP?
$$\Delta \phi = 0 \text{ in between }S_1\text{ and }S_2$$
$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n_1}\big|_{S_1} = C_1, \;\; \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n_2}\big|_{S_2} = C_2$$
Here $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n_1}$ denote the derivatives along the vectors orthogonal to $S_i$. $C_i$ are assumed constants.
If $S_i$ were concentric, the problem is quite standard and uses Legendre polynomails. I am interested in the case when the spheres do not share the centre. I am also not very confident in conformal maps, so if they are absolutely required here, I would like a little bit more commentary.

Circles (per the title) or spheres (per the text)? If circles, you could try setting the problem in the complex plane: you might be able to get somewhere with it by using Mobius transformations (it's a long time since I did anything like this, though!). Otherwise you might be looking at numerical methods (though again, transforming the space would be a natural thing to do here)

@ChrisLewis spheres unfortunately

You should use bispherical coordinates.

@Gonçalo 's suggestion looks to be the way to go, but the linked MathWorld article doesn't actually explain much at all! The Wikipedia article is slightly better (it at least explains what the coordinates mean, and how the system is derived): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bispherical_coordinates
